Why is my Ender 3 v2 Neo bed overheating without any interaction?
I have just purchased my third  Ender 3 V2, this time a Neo. After unpacking and assembling it, then switching it on, without any prompt from me the bed starts heating, and carries on heating until it reaches 110 °C when a warning "bed overheating" flashes on the screen.
The hot end reacts correctly to the input on the display but even when I set the bed temperature to 55 °C it ignores that command and carries on to 110 °C.
How can I rectify this?

Get this back to your supplier and claim the warranty, don't tinker with it, you should get a replacement. Without input, the bed should never heat up, something is obviously broken or installed incorrectly.

When there is no connection between the bed thermistor contacts, the Ender3 runs into thermal runaway protection.
Two small white wires should run from your motherboard to the heated bed and is probably disconnected somewhere.
The Ender3 has some places where this fragile cable can be pulled by the gantry, so look out for a break in the wire and also at the contacts of the (glass) thermistor)
A replacement thermistor is cheap, but look out for the right one as there are many different resistor values available.
If you have a multimeter, you can try measuring the resistor between the contacts of the thermistor wire and compare the values to the ones you measure on the wires of the hotend thermistor. They should be in the same ballpark.

RETURN THIS DANGER
For whatever reason, the bed is getting power. That means it heats. That means it is DANGEROUS. Turn it off, separate it from mains power, don't use it, and return to seller as dangerously defective.
Possible reasons
Among many other reasons, these seem to be possible but can't easily be fixed without knowing exactly what you do:

The heater control chip is burnt out and does not trigger off.
The firmware is botched and sets a print temperature from the launch.
A wire is connected to the "high" voltage supply instead of the heater port.


That’s weird. It’s could be a broken thermistor or connection with your mb. Try seeing if these are good and also contact support, bc this is really weird.

Welcome to 3D Printing! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Could you [edit] and expand upon your answer, because, as it stands, your answer could seem to be more of a comment rather than a full answer? Also, please don't use text abbreviations (mb, bc), as their meaning may not be obvious to non-native English speaking readers.

The bed showing a wrong temperature? yes, might be a broken thermosensor. But heating?! DANGER.
